# Concurrent ObjectPool using ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

**Main ObjectPool Class**: It uses atomic operations and a concurrent linked queue to achieve the best performance compared to Apache commons pool. I want to make sure there are no concurrency issues even though unit tests passed without any issue.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ObjectPool<T> {
    private static final boolean LOGS_ENABLED = false;

    private AtomicInteger totalObjectsCount = new AtomicInteger();
    private AtomicInteger pooledObjectsCount = new AtomicInteger();

    private int initialPoolSize;
    private int maximumPoolSize;

    private Class<T> type;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T>();
    private Object waitSync = new Object();

    public ObjectPool(Class<T> type) {
        this(type, 0);
    }

    public ObjectPool(Class<T> type, int initialPoolSize) {
        this(type, initialPoolSize, -1);
    }

    public ObjectPool(Class<T> type, int initialPoolSize, int maximumPoolSize) {
        if(initialPoolSize < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("initialPoolSize");
        }

        if(maximumPoolSize < -1 || (maximumPoolSize != -1 && initialPoolSize > maximumPoolSize)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("maximumPoolSize");
        }

        if(type != null) {
             try {
                 type.getConstructor();
             } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                 throw new IllegalArgumentException("type", e);
             }
        } else {
            if(getClass() == ObjectPool.class) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("type");
            }
        }

        this.initialPoolSize = initialPoolSize;
        this.maximumPoolSize = maximumPoolSize;
        this.type = type;
        if(type != null) {
            initialize();
        }
    }

    public int getInitialPoolSize() {
        return initialPoolSize;
    }

    public int getMaximumPoolSize() {
        return maximumPoolSize;
    }

    public int getPooledObjectsCount() {
        return pooledObjectsCount.get();
    }

    public int getTotalObjectsCount() {
        return totalObjectsCount.get();
    }

    protected void initialize() {
        List<T> itemList = new LinkedList<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < initialPoolSize; i++) {
            try {
                itemList.add(take());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        for (T item:
                itemList) {
            put(item);
        }
    }

    protected T create() {
        if(type != null) {
            try {
                return type.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e);
            }
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
        T object;
        while ((object = queue.poll()) == null) {
            if(maximumPoolSize <= 0 || this.totalObjectsCount.get() < maximumPoolSize) {
                boolean success = false;
                try {
                    int totalObjectsCount = this.totalObjectsCount.incrementAndGet();
                    if (maximumPoolSize <= 0 || totalObjectsCount <= maximumPoolSize) {
                        object = create();
                        if (LOGS_ENABLED) {
                            Log.info("%s Object Created :- Created : %d, Maximum : %d", getClass().getSimpleName(), this.totalObjectsCount.get(), maximumPoolSize);
                        }
                        success = true;
                        return object;
                    }
                } finally {
                    if(!success) {
                        this.totalObjectsCount.decrementAndGet();
                        // Notify other sleeping takers, so that one of them can continue creating new object.
                        synchronized (waitSync) {
                            waitSync.notify();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            synchronized (waitSync) {
                if (this.pooledObjectsCount.get() <= 0) {
                    if (LOGS_ENABLED) {
                        Log.info("%s Waiting for Object :- Created : %d, Maximum : %d", getClass().getSimpleName(), this.totalObjectsCount.get(), maximumPoolSize);
                    }
                    waitSync.wait();
                }
            }
        }
        this.pooledObjectsCount.decrementAndGet();
        return object;
    }

    public void put(T e) {
        queue.add(e);
        // Notify consumer when first object arrives
        if(this.pooledObjectsCount.incrementAndGet() <= 1) {
            synchronized (waitSync) {
                waitSync.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("PooledObjectsCount : %d, TotalObjectsCount : %d, MaxPoolSize : %d", getPooledObjectsCount(), getTotalObjectsCount(), getMaximumPoolSize());
    }
}
```

**Unit Test Class:**

```
public class ObjectPoolTest {



    @Test
    public void testConstructors() throws Exception {

        ObjectPool<Object> objectPool = null;

        try {
            objectPool = null;
            objectPool = new ObjectPool<Object>(null, 10, 20);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }
        Assert.assertNull(objectPool);

        try {
            objectPool = null;
            objectPool = new ObjectPool<Object>(Object.class, -10, 5);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }
        Assert.assertNull(objectPool);

        try {
            objectPool = null;
            objectPool = new ObjectPool<Object>(Object.class, 10, -20);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }
        Assert.assertNull(objectPool);

        try {
            objectPool = null;
            objectPool = new ObjectPool<Object>(Object.class, 10, 20);
            Assert.assertTrue(objectPool.getInitialPoolSize() == 10);
            Assert.assertTrue(objectPool.getMaximumPoolSize() == 20);
            Assert.assertTrue(objectPool.getPooledObjectsCount() == 10);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }
        Assert.assertNotNull(objectPool);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUnboundedPool() {
        // Unbounded Pool test is risky on build server. Just test it on dev machine.
        testSingleProducerAndSingleConsumer(new ObjectPool<Object>(Object.class));
        testSingleProducerAndMultipleConsumer(new ObjectPool<Object>(Object.class));
        testMultipleProducerAndSingleConsumer(new ObjectPool<Object>(Object.class));
        testMultipleProducerAndMultipleConsumer(new ObjectPool<Object>(Object.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void testBoundedPool() {
        testSingleProducerAndSingleConsumer(new ObjectPool<Object>(Object.class, 100000, 200000));
        testSingleProducerAndMultipleConsumer(new ObjectPool<Object>(Object.class, 100000, 200000));
        testMultipleProducerAndSingleConsumer(new ObjectPool<Object>(Object.class, 100000, 200000));
        testMultipleProducerAndMultipleConsumer(new ObjectPool<Object>(Object.class, 100000, 200000));
    }

    private void testSingleProducerAndSingleConsumer(ObjectPool<Object> objectPool) {
        testUsingMultipleThreads(objectPool, false, false);
    }

    private void testSingleProducerAndMultipleConsumer(ObjectPool<Object> objectPool) {
        testUsingMultipleThreads(objectPool, false, true);
    }

    private void testMultipleProducerAndSingleConsumer(ObjectPool<Object> objectPool) {
        testUsingMultipleThreads(objectPool, true, false);
    }

    private void testMultipleProducerAndMultipleConsumer(ObjectPool<Object> objectPool) {
        testUsingMultipleThreads(objectPool, true, true);
    }

    private void testUsingMultipleThreads(ObjectPool<Object> objectPool, boolean multipleProducer, boolean multipleConsumer) {
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Object> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();;
        int testDuration = 10 * 1000;
        int threadCount = 50;

        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
            // Create consumer threads.
            if(i == 0 || multipleConsumer) {
                threads.add(new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime <= testDuration) {
                                queue.add(objectPool.take());
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        }
                    }
                }));
            }

            // Create producer threads
            if(i == 0 || multipleProducer) {
                threads.add(new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime <= testDuration) {
                            Object object = queue.poll();
                            if (object == null) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            objectPool.put(object);
                        }
                    }
                }));
            }
        }

        threads.forEach(thread -> thread.start());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2 * testDuration);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        // Add all borrowed items back to object pool.
        Object object;
        while ((object = queue.poll()) != null) {
            objectPool.put(object);
        }

        // Wait more time, so it will allow time to consumer threads to unblock from take() and exit.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        // Check if any thread is still working. In that case test is failed.
        threads.forEach(thread -> {
            if(thread.isAlive()) {
                Arrays.stream(thread.getStackTrace()).forEach(st -> System.out.printf("%s%n", st));
                Assert.assertFalse(objectPool.toString(), thread.isAlive());
            }
        });

        Assert.assertTrue(objectPool.toString(),objectPool.getPooledObjectsCount() == objectPool.getTotalObjectsCount());

        if(objectPool.getMaximumPoolSize() > 0) {
            Assert.assertTrue(objectPool.toString(), objectPool.getTotalObjectsCount() <= objectPool.getMaximumPoolSize());
        }
    }
}
```